# How to highlight important parts (with a gray background)

Tags: color, boxes, framed, highlighting

In the below link

> http://www.math.uiowa.edu/~goodman/algebrabook.dir/bookmt.pdf

the author highlights anything which is important using a greyish color background. For example, if you see **Equation 1.5.3** (which on page 22 of the book) it is highlighted in grey. I would like to know the TeX commands for producing similar output.

Comment: check out the `mdframed` package.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.

Comment: In addition to Harish’s comment I recommend to define commands and environments for those thing you want to highlight. So all of them look the same but can be change easily afterword if necessary. After checking `mdframed` you may post a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) to show, what you’ve tried so far …

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, `mdframed` is perfect for this. You can combine it with your favourite `theorem` package too- in the MWE below I've used it with `ntheorem`, but there's nothing to stop you from using `amsthm` or something similar.

[image]

This example is very simple, but you can get very sophisticated using `tikz` or `pstricks` as the engine, as shown in the [excellent documentation](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/mdframed)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}     % for colour
\usepackage{lipsum}     % for sample text
\usepackage{ntheorem}   % for theorem-like environments
\usepackage{mdframed}   % for framing

\theoremstyle{break}
\theoremheaderfont{\bfseries}
\newmdtheoremenv[%
linecolor=gray,leftmargin=60,%
rightmargin=40,
backgroundcolor=gray!40,%
innertopmargin=0pt,%
ntheorem]{myprop}{Proposition}[section]

\begin{document}

\section{mdframed for the win}
\begin{myprop}
\lipsum[1]
\end{myprop}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is not working for me due to some reason. I am not getting the output.

Comment: @chandrasekhar add `\listfiles` immediately before your `\begin{document}`- it sounds like your system needs to be updated

Answer (score 20):

With `tcolorbox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[breakable, theorems, skins]{tcolorbox}
\tcbset{enhanced}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\mybox}[2][gray!20]{%
\begin{tcolorbox}[   %% Adjust the following parameters at will.
        breakable,
        left=0pt,
        right=0pt,
        top=0pt,
        bottom=0pt,
        colback=#1,
        colframe=#1,
        width=\dimexpr\textwidth\relax, 
        enlarge left by=0mm,
        boxsep=5pt,
        arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt,
        ]
        #2
\end{tcolorbox}
}

\begin{document}
\mybox[green!20]{\kant[1]}
\mybox{\kant[2]}
\mybox[red!20!white]{\kant}

\end{document}
```

[image]

`tcolorbox` integrates flawlessly with theorem packages and math. Further, it can produce more fancier boxes than one can imagine. I feel that this is the best option to adopt when one has to highlight text / math / theorems. Though I have defined a command, new environments can also be defined with `tcolorbox`. For details, `texdoc tcolorbox` or visit www.texdoc.net.

A sample preposition:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\newtcbtheorem{Proposition}{Proposition}%
{breakable,colframe=red!50!white!50!black,fonttitle=\bfseries}{}

\begin{document}
\begin{Proposition}{This is my proposition}{}
  \kant
\end{Proposition}
\end{document}
```

## Earlier attempt:

Sorry for joining late. I would like to add to cmhughes's excellent answer. Though his reply is already accepted as the answer, I wish to share mine. My method is simple and direct where colors can be changed very easily.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newcommand*{\mybox}[2]{\colorbox{#1!30}{\parbox{.98\linewidth}{#2}}}
\begin{document}
%=====================
\section{First section}
%=====================
\mybox{green}{\lipsum[1]}
\par
\noindent\mybox{red}{\lipsum[2]}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: this won't break across pages though...

Comment: @cmhughes Correct. But the file provided above by the OP does not require breaking across pages. It is for just highlighting small bits of text (like a line or two. I also go with `mdframed` for things like these. (as I commented above) My answer is added just for fun.

Comment: @HarishKumar:Very nice way of doing it!

Comment: What if I would like to add other text than \kant[2]? Putting simple text there, or sections, results in an error.