# Mark parts requiring rework

Tags: workflow

Doing my first more complicated paper using LaTeX, I wonder if there are any possibilities to specially mark sections or parts requiring rework.

It would be nice if those sections appeared in a special highlight in the output and could be connected to a short comment.

For example, being able to write something like the following would be great:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, \rework[spellcheck]{consetetur sadipscing} elitr.
```

Are there any predefined tags for doing so?
Or should I simply use highlighting like shown in [How to highlight important parts (with a gray background)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46828/how-to-highlight-important-parts-with-a-gray-background) ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Have a look on the package `todonotes` on [CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/todonotes). You can mark with `\todo[author]{remark}`. It gives you the remark as margin and you can print a list of todos.

An advantage is that you can switch off all your todo notes with the package class option `disable`.

Comment: Thanks - even more than I was looking for.
See http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5180/17533 on problems with todos appearing on the wrong side.

Answer (score 2):

This may not be a direct answer to your question but you might want to consider to use [Org-mode for drafting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/54211/5701) rather than using LaTeX directly. You can then use [Org-mode's features for tracking TODO items](http://orgmode.org/manual/TODO-Items.html#TODO-Items) and export your document to LaTeX when you are done.

In Org-mode you can mark a headline as either of the following (predefined) statuses (with <kbd>C-c C-t</kbd> or <kbd>S-right</kbd>/<kbd>S-left</kbd>:

- (unmarked)
- TODO
- DONE

You can then get a list of every TODO item in a document. You can also set priorities and deadlines for headlines.