# problem with mdframed commands

Tags: environments, mdframed

I was trying to highlight some text as shown in [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46828/how-to-highlight-important-parts-with-a-gray-background), but I'm having problems. the following works for me

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor=gray!20, linecolor=white]
\lipsum[1]
\end{mdframed}
\end{document}
```

but when I try to use his exact same code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}     % for colour
\usepackage{lipsum}     % for sample text
\usepackage{ntheorem}   % for theorem-like environments
\usepackage{mdframed}   % for framing

\theoremstyle{break}
\theoremheaderfont{\bfseries}
\newmdtheoremenv[%
linecolor=gray,leftmargin=60,%
rightmargin=40,
backgroundcolor=gray!40,%
innertopmargin=0pt,%
ntheorem]{myprop}{Proposition}[section]

\begin{document}

\section{mdframed for the win}
\begin{myprop}
\lipsum[1]
\end{myprop}

\end{document}
```

I get an error `"Undefined control sequence. l.10 \newmdtheoremenv"`.Do you know what could be the problem? I'm kind of new with latex and I have no clue.

Comment: Your code runs fine for me. May be it is time to update your tex distro! `:-)`

Comment: Yes, you need at least a 2011 distribution. I can reproduce your problem with TeXLive 2010, but works fine with TeXLive 2011, and TeXLive 2012.

Comment: [how-do-i-update-my-tex-distribution](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55437/how-do-i-update-my-tex-distribution)

Comment: I think I had the 2011 distribution, but anyway, I updated it and it worked now. Thank you.