# Grey box around the text

Tags: highlighting

I have to write a `newenvironment`, which plots a grey box around the text.

I can't decide which package I should be use. I am writing a dissertation and I want that some text sections have a grey box around the text.

Which package should I use for my `newenvironment{greyBox}`?

So you see down newenvironment it produces grey box around my text, but I want use this one

```
\vspace{5mm}
\begingroup
\leftskip4em
\rightskip\leftskip\textit{``text here.''}
\vspace{5mm}
\endgroup
```

in my newenvironment, but i can't integrate into it. The text in newenvironment should to intend right and left.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{mdframed}

\newenvironment{bla}%
  {\begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor=lightgray]}%
  {\end{mdframed}}

  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\begin{bla}

\begin{itemize}

 \item Beccari 
 \item Gregorio  
\item Blue  

\end{itemize}
\end{bla}

\end{document}
```

I want exactly, that text + box are centered.

I want like this picture [image]

Only the red part should be have a grey box, but I don't find still yet a solution.

Comment: You might want to look into the [`mdframed`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mdframed) package, that could do this for you.

Comment: Can I change this example in newenvironment.                  \usepackage{color}
\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.75}

\newcommand\greybox[1]{%
  \vskip\baselineskip%
  \par\noindent\colorbox{lightgray}{%
    \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}#1\end{minipage}%
  }%
  \vskip\baselineskip%
}

Comment: I can't open the page --> Service Temporarily Unavailable

Comment: you might want to edit your question to put the code from your comment into it, formatted as block code - it would be much easier to follow.

Comment: I'm sure it will be up soon, but googling `mdframed manual` should get you a copy of the manual from elsewhere.

Comment: You might wanna check these topics: [`framed` or `mdframed`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71554/framed-or-mdframed-pros-cons) and [`tcolorbox` or `mdframed`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/135871/what-are-the-relative-strong-and-weak-points-between-tcolorbox-and-mdframed).

Comment: @ChrisH I edited my question ;)

Comment: Marking up blocks of code can be a little tricky, I edited your question to help out, but you should use the preview pane in the future to make sure your post looks like you want it to.

Comment: [How to highlight important parts (with a gray background)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/46828)

Comment: @cmhughes thank you for this example but this is for theorem, but I will try it.

Comment: @Harish Kumar I solved the problem different with mdframed, but your example is really well. Thank you for this. I have to decide which one I use at last.

Comment: @Harish Kumar I tried something and notice that the colorbox jump on the other page, when the box don't suit on the page, but I don't want this. When the box don't suit on the page then it should be separate in the other page. I hope you understand me.